# WebGL - compileShader syntax error

Tags: webgl

## Fragment Shader code

```
function getFragmentShader() {
    return ["in vec3 ex_Color;",
    "out vec4 out_Color;",
    "void main(void) {",
    "out_Color = vec4(ex_Color,1.0);",
    "}"].join("\n");
}
```

When use this function to get the shader string and compile, it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:0:1:": syntax error
```

I am using chrome to test this. I am not sure how and when the `"` is getting introduced. When I see the string passed to gl.shaderSource the `"` does not show up. Any input to resolve the issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use HTSL shader code instead of OpenGL ES Shading Language (GLSL ES).
As well try to pass single string instead of array.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was primarly in Shader Program where a division like x / y has to be both Float if either value is a Float value. Chrome pointed the issue as `"` but the Mozilla was pretty accurate in pointing out the exact issue.